# What did Bannon mean when he said that Rice "operationalized" the NSC?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, politics

According to several news sources, Stephen K. Bannon said in a statement today that "Susan Rice **operationalized** the NSC [National Security Council] during the last administration" and that he "was put on to ensure that it was de-operationalized”.

The [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/05/us/politics/national-security-council-stephen-bannon.html) dryly remarks that "Mr. Bannon did not explain what he meant by “operationalized” or how his presence on the committee had ensured it would not be."

Merriam-Webster's defines "operationalize" as "to make operational". Operational has several meanings, of which two appear to deserve consideration in this context:

- of, engaged in, or connected with execution of military or naval operations in campaign or battle;
- ready for or in condition to undertake a destined function.

It is probably not bad if the National Security Council is in a condition to undertake its actual destined function, and part of this function is certainly "connected" to military operations; so this cannot be what Bannon wanted to revert.

Did Bannon want to suggest that Rice made the NSC ready to perform some other function, i.e. a hidden agenda? Or did he use the word in a completely non-standard fashion? Is the word en vogue in the alt-right movement?

Comment: You've already given the definition of 'operationalize', and that's the only meaning this site is qualified to answer questions about. Political implications of what Bannon was saying are for another site. our Politics site might be the best place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about political implications rather than English language.

Comment: Without studying the messy details, I would tend to interpret the word to imply that the NSC was taken from a passive "advisor" role to a more active role where it directs what operations are undertaken.  Of course the devil is in the details here -- a lot of difference between saying "Hey CIA, could you collect some info about El Dictator du jour?" to planning and carrying out an invasion of Syria.

Comment: @DJClayworth DavePHD's answer illustrates very well how this use of "operationalization" is based on a specific meaning of "operation", which is not directly military, but also not just "functioning". If Bannon deplores that the NSC has been made operational he means neither that they finally got a whiteboard and a copier; nor that the NSC's attention shifted from other topics to military ones (those were its concerns all along). He means that they actually *did* stuff, as opposed to being all talk. "Operational" assumes perhaps aspects of "transactional". Actually what Hot Licks said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The meaning is explained in the book [Running the World: The Inside Story of the National Security Council and the Architects of American Power](https://books.google.com/books?id=1N1DleUGufwC&pg=PA134&dq=operationalized%20%22national%20security%20council%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicj6SEv5DTAhUFYyYKHdXzDU0Q6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=operationalized%20%22national%20security%20council%22&f=false):

> This mission is often cited as marking the “operationalization” of the national security advisor and the NSC—a dangerous line to have crossed in light of mistakes made with later NSC “operations” such as Iran-Contra.

The [Yale Law Journal](http://digitalcommons.law.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2949&context=fss_papers) also has a section heading:

> *The NSC Operationalized*
>
> Similarly, the operationalization of the NSC commenced not with the peregrinations of Oliver North, or Robert McFarlane's odyssey to Tehran with Bible and birthday cake, but with Henry Kissinger's secret trip to mainland China...

Also, from the [Senate Foreign Relations Subcommittee record](https://books.google.com/books?id=w3RJAQAAIAAJ&q=%22operationalized%20the%20nsc%22&dq=%22operationalized%20the%20nsc%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI9fHqxpDTAhVJyyYKHQJCBmkQ6AEIGjAA):

> Six months after the fact, we learned that the President has "operationalized" the NSC, secretly dispatching his National Security Assistant abroad to conduct discussions with foreign leaders that ran contrary to our public position.

The [law creating the NSC](http://legisworks.org/congress/80/publaw-253.pdf) stated :

> The function of the Council shall be to advise the President with respect to the integration of domestic, foreign, and military policies relating to the national security so as to enable the military services and the other departments and agencies of the Government to cooperate more effectively in matters involving the national security

So "operationalized" is relative to the "advise" function originally set forth.

Comment: @Xanne Is that better now?

Comment: Yes. What mission was it that marked the operationalization--just curious.  I could look it up.  Apparently pre-Reagan presidency.

Comment: @Xanne The first two references mean Henry Kissinger 's secret 1971 trip to China.  The third reference is talking about a person being sent secretly in the timeframe of Iraq's invasion of Kuwait.

Comment: @Xanne Actually I think the third reference means McFarlane's trip to Iran https://newrepublic.com/article/69832/the-tragedy-bud-mcfarlane

Comment: The Yale paper is very interesting, thanks for digging this out. On p. 1269 is another quote which illustrates the meaning, "The NSC's accumulation of decisionmaking, then decision-executing, power at the expense of the State Department...". Did you just google that or do you have a background in the field? The answer came quickly.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Just google, but I'm slightly familiar from answering this http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36990/does-the-us-national-security-council-have-the-ability-to-authorize-assassination see also "National Security Advisor Susan Rice, who has helped codify targeted killing criteria by creating the Disposition Matrix database" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_National_Security_Council

Comment: The answer didn't mention it, but it sounds like the connotation of 'operationalize' is similar to 'activating special forces'. It has a sinister quality to it, as though it is to be kept secret and behind the scenes. This would make sense in context as Bannon (probably) believes the previous administration was not upfront about their activities and policies. The word is probably DC beltway jargon.

Comment: How would "advice" have validity without up-to-date experience, e.g., without **any** actual meetings with foreign diplomats/agents or travel to foreign locations? It's not clear how `discussions with foreign leaders` for example have relevance. Is it merely from tracing the generally known usage history of the word (which seems appropriate in this site)?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't fit in context with me either. To "-ize" something is to change its nature.

Weaponize - make a weapon version.  Dehumanize - render someone less than human.

Then again, Bannon tends to come up with a lot of terms that don't make that much sense, to the point where I'm convinced he's trying to sound "military" and failing badly.  In this case, his usage of "operationalize" implies that the NSC was originally tasked to be passive oversight of the nation's security apparatus, not an active participant via Rice's leadership (not that this actually went on, just trying to get a handle on how Bannon sees it.)